# Complex Query MSACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS ACCESS table named Sales, and it contain 5 fields and need to create a query to get a report showing the sale of each item.. 
Table Example..

Sales Table

```
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|   SaleDate | ItemID | SaleQty | SalePrice | SaleTotal |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1105 |   30.00 |      5.25 |    157.50 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1105 |    2.00 |      5.25 |     10.50 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1105 |   10.00 |      6.00 |     60.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1105 |    4.00 |      6.00 |     24.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1106 |    3.00 |      8.00 |     24.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1106 |    8.00 |      8.00 |     64.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1106 |   12.00 |      8.50 |    102.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1106 |    6.00 |      8.50 |     51.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1105 |   12.00 |      6.00 |     72.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1105 |    9.00 |      6.00 |     54.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1105 |    1.00 |      6.50 |      6.50 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1105 |    2.00 |      6.50 |     13.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1106 |    7.00 |      8.50 |     59.50 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1106 |    4.00 |      8.50 |     34.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1106 |    3.00 |      8.70 |     26.10 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1106 |   16.00 |      8.70 |    139.20 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+`
```

it's so difficult to explain.. but i try
In the table exist two record (First)

Example:
The first two records in the table has the same SaleDate,ItemID and SalePrice

what i need to do is SUM the field SaleQty with all the records that have the same SaleDate,ItemID and SalePrice
(Also SUM the SaleTotal)

Sales Query Result (Needed)

```
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|   SaleDate | ItemID | SaleQty | SalePrice | SaleTotal |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1105 |   32.00 |      5.25 |    168.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1105 |   14.00 |      6.00 |     10.50 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1106 |   11.00 |      8.00 |     88.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 02/25/2017 |   1106 |   18.00 |      8.50 |    153.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1105 |   21.00 |      6.00 |    126.00 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1105 |    3.00 |      6.50 |     19.50 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1106 |   11.00 |      8.50 |     93.50 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 03/25/2017 |   1106 |   19.00 |      8.70 |    165.30 |
+------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+`
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
SELECT SaleDate, ItemID, SalePrice, SUM(SaleQty) AS SaleQty, SUM(SaleTotal) AS SaleTotal

FROM Sales

GROUP BY SaleDate, ItemID, SalePrice
```

To learn more about *group by* in MS Access, see https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/GROUP-BY-Clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0